Force Ubuntu to Download Debian Packages
My goal is to download on a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) machine packages for an offline Debian 11 (Bullseye) server.
For this, I have first disabled all relevant ubuntu sources in /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list/* and added a debian source list:
deb [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free

deb [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free

deb [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main contrib non-free

deb [trusted=yes] http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free

refreshed the package list via sudo apt update and then download the relevant packages with the command:
sudo apt-get download <Package> -t bullseye -d
Some packages will indeed be downloaded. xz-utils, for instance, will be downloaded from the debian repository.
The output for its apt-cache policy xz-utils is:
Version table:  
> *** 5.2.5-2.1~deb11u1 500
  500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
  500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages
  100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
> 5.2.5-2ubuntu1 500
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages

However, most often than not, apt tries to download the ubuntu version, even when the debian version is the only repo available. When downloading ufw, for instance, I get the following output for sudo apt-cache policy ufw:
Version table:  
> *** 0.36.1-4ubuntu0.1 500
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
> 0.36-7.1 500
    500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main i386 Packages

and when I try to download the package, I receive:

Error: No source could be found to download version
'0.36.1-4ubuntu0.1' of 'ufw

and once I enable the ubuntu sources, it downloads the packages for ubuntu, even though the debian repo is available and has the same package.
How can I "force" Ubuntu to download the Debian packages, and not look for the version that's available only in Ubuntu repos? "-t bullseye" does not seem to work.
I'm trying to automate the download process in a bash script, so I'm desperately searching for a way to do this as flexible as possible

It reads to me that you're trying to break your system.. Ubuntu and Debian never actually align, especially on released products, as Ubuntu LTS is the even year, and Debian releases its LTS on the odd year; beyond their being differences in how many packages are built due to differences in approach. What you're doing will just create a frakensystem.

@guiverc Hmm.. why do you think it creates a Frankenstein system, when all I'm doing is downloading the packages?

Refer https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian  where you'll note a Fraken is referred to as mixing up packages built for other systems (be it other releases, or other distributions...).   I'm using my Ubuntu oracular system currently; its closest to my Debian trixie system but they're still different (even when neither is in a freeze state!).  Debian & Ubuntu stable systems NEVER align due to differences in release dates & packaging intention/differences.

@guiverc thanks for the input and help! Will look into that

@thelearner one thing to take away from my answer is that it is rather easy to set up containers these days (Docker, LXC, systemd-nspawn, etc.). You'd be better of just starting a Docker (or any of the other types) container of Debian and using it download whatever you want.

I tested it out on a Docker container of 24.04, and got these results:
# apt download -t bullseye -d bash
Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble/main arm64 bash arm64 5.2.21-2ubuntu4 [780 kB]
Fetched 780 kB in 2s (323 kB/s)

It downloaded the Ubuntu version, as you described. But using /<target> instead worked:
# apt download -d bash/bullseye
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 bash arm64 5.1-2+deb11u1 [1376 kB]
Fetched 1376 kB in 0s (15.2 MB/s)


Works perfectly!
